# Transforming comma to number and limiting to 3 decimal places

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have values structured like this:

```
0,132
6,0999999999999999E-2
```

And I want it to become this:

```
0.132
0.060
```

Using an sql query in oracle db?

Turning the comma to dot and maintaining only 3 decimal points. Tried CAST and TO_NUMBER with formatting but it didn't work.

Comment: What is the data type of your original data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ORACLE's to_number,replace and round functions like this:

```
SELECT round(to_number(replace(string,',','.')),3) FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the optional third argument to [the `to_number()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions211.htm) to specify the comma as the decimal separator. With a CTE to provide your string values:

```
with t (str) as (
  select '0,132' from dual
  union all select '6,0999999999999999E-2' from dual
)
select to_number(str, '9D9999999999999999EEEE', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')
  as num
from t;

      NUM
----------
      .132
      .061
```

The format model needs to have enough digits after the decimal separator for the most precise number in your table. The [`EEEE` format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51074) handles the scientific notation.

You can then use [`round()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions155.htm) or [`trunc()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions221.htm) to restrict to three decimal places; rounding makes no difference with your sample values, but truncating shows that the second value goes from 0.061 to 0.060:

```
with t (str) as (
  select '0,1322' from dual
  union all select '6,0999999999999999E-2' from dual
)
select trunc(to_number(str, '9D9999999999999999EEEE',
  'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.'''), 3)  as num
from t;

       NUM
----------
      .132
       .06
```

You can use `to_char()` (or your client/application) to show leading and trailing zeros if you prefer.

You could also set the session [NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams154.htm) to `',.'`, but it's safer to not assume anyone running this query will have a particular setting and make it part of the query.